# Deriving revenues from the use or provision of the Instagram APIs

Tags: instagram

I would like some assistance, ideally from someone at Instagram to clarify a part of the API terms of use.

There are various apps and third party websites which use the Instagram API and also generate revenue, either through means of advertising or directly charging users a fee for features/access. Even something simple like a website which uses your pictures through the API to make prints generates strong revnue.

How are they getting around the following API terms? If I were to develop a third party website that generated revenue, would it get banned? I am not looking to charge users to access the website, but the website in general will generate a revenue and does use Instagram API for authenticating users and pulling pictures.

***"You shall not: Sell, lease, or sublicense the Instagram APIs or access thereto or derive revenues from the use or provision of the Instagram APIs, whether for direct commercial or monetary gain or otherwise, except as set forth below."***

Appreciate any help

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you contact Instagram directly? Good question. Wrong forum.